# Feeds choke on non-existent tag names

Tags: feature-request, tags, feed

I wanted a feed URL that encompassed all questions about French-speaking regions on [Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/). So I tried

https://travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?sort=newest&tagnames=andorra+or+belgium+or+france+or+french-guiana+or+french-polynesia+or+guadalupe+or+luxembourg+or+martinique+or+mayotte+or+monaco+or+quebec+or+reunion+or+saint-martin+or+switzerland

(still missing a few more obscure locales), but

[image: Page Not Found]

It looks like I have to trim the list down to existing tags.

https://travel.stackexchange.com/feeds/tag?sort=newest&tagnames=andorra+or+belgium+or+france+or+french-guiana+or+monaco+or+quebec+or+saint-martin+or+switzerland

That's annoying: if someone asks a question about [mayotte](/questions/tagged/mayotte), it won't be in my feed.

Please **allow non-existent tags in feed URLs**, so that we can build future-proof feeds.